# Localstorage getitem - match to div class

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I have created a simple code, so when the user clicks a child div of 'speaker-cookie' parent, they then set a localstorage value. Code is:-

```
$(".speakers-cookie div").on( "click", function() {
    var speakerpop = $(this).attr("class");
    localStorage.setItem('speaker', speakerpop);
});
```

This is working well, when on another page I want to get the value for the speaker and test IF the value matches a div, then change the colour of the div. I have tried the following:-

```
<script>
    var speakercolor = localStorage.getItem("speaker");
    $('body').find(speakercolor).css('background','red')
</script>
```

Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong here? This is not colouring the div atall.

Thank you

Comment: `.find("." + speakercolor)`

Comment: @Andreas agh thats working! thanks a lot!